# Enable permission to get WiFi details - Android marshmallow

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using wifiwizard, a cordova plugin to get the available wifi networks in ionic framework. It works fine for all the android os except marshmallow. In marshmallow, I need to enable the location to get the same. How to resolve this issue?

Things tried: 
Provided permissions in the wifiwizard-> plugin.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Could anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/09/cordova-android-5.0.0.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your plugins if you are using old plugins.
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/09/cordova-android-5.0.0.html

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```